# How to compare outside value with while loop values?

Tags: php, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields, date-comparison, acfpro

I am trying to write a program that gives me output according to date comparison. I am using ACF repeater where I have put some event start dates and event end dates.

I have four different event start dates so I want to show results according to the date within the loop. This means if one package has 23 May 2022 and the second package has 10 April 2022 so when I compare then the result will come for the first package registration open and for the second package the result will come registration close.

I have tried following code but it is not working.

```
function santy_shortcode_race_categories_event_post(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $result = '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center; background-color:#fff;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-head">
                        <th>Package</th>
                        <th>Age Category</th>
                        <th>Ticket Price</th>
                        <th>Reg. Link</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if (get_field('Race-Categories',$id)) {
        while (the_repeater_field('Race-Categories', $id)) {
            $event_start_date .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+5 hours +30 minutes", strtotime(get_sub_field("ticket_registration_start"))));
            $event_end_date .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+5 hours +30 minutes", strtotime(get_sub_field("ticket_registration_end_date"))));
            $result .='<tr>';
            $result .='<td>'.get_sub_field("package").'</td>';
            $result .='<td>'.get_sub_field("age_category").'</td>';
            $result .='<td>'.get_sub_field("ticket_price").'</td>';
            if ($current_date > $event_start_date) {
                $result .= '<td>Registration Open</td>';
            } else {
                $result .= '<td>Registration Close</td>';
            }
            $result .='</tr>';
        }
    } else {
        $result .='No Any Race categories allocated for this event. Try other events.';
    }
    $result .= '</tbody>
                </table>
                </div>';
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: well - As I see it - then right they all returns closed. 1) - You are comparing `$current_date > $event_start` but the variable you created is called `$event_start_date` - 2) Also I think it should be `$current_date < $event_start_date` since you want the start date to be later than the current date.

Comment: and if you want to be sure - then you should run strtotime on both dates, so you are comparing an integer instead of date formats

Comment: @Stender Thanks I have corrected the variable but the answer is the same, in every table of the row it is showing 'Registration Open' but I have four different event start dates. but  due to while loop, I think it is not running.

Comment: according to the documentation on acf - `the_repeater_field()` is deprecated for `have_rows()` since it was causing undesired results when also used within an if-statment. which is what you are doing here - Maybe change that?

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/